# javax.naming.NamenotFoundException: name postgre is not bound in this context

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, struts

i am new to struts .. i have been trying to connect to postgresql using a datasource in tomcat 6, but i get the following error..

```
  *javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name postgre is not bound in this Context
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
    javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    strutsTutorial.UserRegistrationAction.execute(UserRegistrationAction.java:30)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.jav
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)*
```

my context.xml file in tomcat config folder is..

```
***<Context>
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="jdbc/strutsTutorial"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              DriverClassname="org.postgresql.Driver"

              url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/strutstutorial"
              username="postgres"
              password=""
              maxActive="20"
              maxIdle="10"
              maxWait="-1"
    />

</Context>***
```

and my action class..am using struts1.1 is...

```
 **package strutsTutorial;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import javax.naming.InitialContext;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
    import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
     public class UserRegistrationAction extends Action {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserRegistrationAction.class);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest             
    request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    log.trace("in execute method of UserregistrationAction.class...");
    Connection conn =null;
    InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();  
    if(cxt == null) {
        throw new Exception("oh haaa no context");
    }
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)cxt.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/strutsTutorial");
    if(ds == null) {
        throw new Exception("datasource not found");
    }
    UserRegistrationForm userForm = (UserRegistrationForm) form;

    System.out.println("entered firstname is" + userForm.getFirstName());

    if(isCancelled(request)) {
        return mapping.findForward("welcome");
    }
    else
         conn =  ds.getConnection();
        try{
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
            "insert into USERDB " +
            "(firstName)" +
            " values (?)");
            stmt.setString(1,userForm.getFirstName());
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            }finally{
            conn.close();
            }
        return mapping.findForward("success");

    }
    }**
```

could someone please explain me where am going wrong??

Comment: Something is asking for the JNDI resource with the name 'postgre' but that doesn't exist in JNDI. Did your code previously ask for the datasource by this name? Perhaps some old code is still deployed? Have you tried fully undeploying/cleaning out your webapp from Tomcat and then redeploying?

Comment: thanks for the response, i am using this code from eclipse, and tried to restart the server many times...i am still  getting the postgre part...dont know where it is coming from...